# Filter Splunk response using queries from ansible playbook

Tags: api, rest, ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

Currently we manually monitor splunk dashboards during our deploys. We would like to automate this. For this, we would like to come up with an ansible playbook with the splunk queries. This playbook will be run during deployment.

I am successfully able to make connection to splunk, but I am not able to get the search query working

```
####
# type: task
#
# vars:
#   5xxcheck_output(str,command): raw output from command
#   5xxcheck_response(str,command): raw output to json
#
# desc:
# uses splunk to get 5xxcheck

---
- name: Tasks to query splunk
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: get search_id for 5xx check from splunk
      uri:
        url: https://<splunk_instance>/services/search/jobs
        follow_redirects: all
        method: POST
        user: xxxxxx
        password: xxxxxxx
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body: "search host=tc1* ResponseCode=500 earliest=-15m"
        body_format: raw
        validate_certs: no
        status_code: 201
        return_content: true
      register: search_id
    - debug: msg="{{ search_id.status }}"

    - name: use the search_id to get the 5xx check results
      uri:
        url: https://<splunk_instance>/services/search/jobs/{{ search_id }}/results/
        method: GET
        user: xxxxxx
        password: xxxxxxx
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: raw
        return_content: true
      register: 5xxcheck_output
      until: 5xxcheck_output.status > 0 and 5xxcheck_output.status != 500

    - name: Put results into 5xxcheck_response
      set_fact:
        5xxcheck_response: "{{ 5xxcheck_output.json }}"

    - name: Print 5xxcheck_response if -v
      debug:
        var: 5xxcheck_response
        verbosity: 1
```

I would like to use uri module to parameterize the splunk search. I am able to execute the following 2 steps from terminal, to get the response

Step1: Get the SID(Search ID)

```
curl -u  user:pwd -k https://<splunk-instance>/services/search/jobs -d search="search host=t1* ResponseCode=200 earliest=-15m"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1604947864.xxxxxx</sid>
</response>
```

Step2: Use the SID to get the response

```
curl -u user:pwd -k https://<splunk-instance>/services/search/jobs/<SID>/results/ --get -d output_mode=raw
```

Comment: Please provide the result of the first curl command,

Comment: @garylopez updated the response of first curl command. Basically, it returns the sid (search_id)

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- name: Tasks to query splunk
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: get search_id for 5xx check from splunk
      uri:
        url: https://splunk_instance/services/search/jobs/
        follow_redirects: all
        method: POST
        user: xxxxx
        password: xxxxx
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: form-urlencoded
        status_code: [200, 201, 202]
        body:
          - [ search, "search host=t1* ResponseCode=500 earliest=-15m" ]
          - [ output_mode, "json" ]
        validate_certs: no
        return_content: true
      register: search_id
    - debug: msg="{{ search_id }}"
```

This worked out for me. Now I get the valid sid as a response when I run this playbook.